# Custom Service Method missing while creating SOAP webservices in ADF

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I created a function inside ShipServiceImpl.java to be used as webservice.After that while going to ShipServiceModule.xml > Webservice > SOAP > Service Custom Method the above created method is not available.
Here the function definition:

```
public class ShipServiceImpl extends ApplicationModuleImpl{

public List<ResponseVO> updateLine(String orderNumber,String customer,String qty)
{


return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you create a method that returns a simple type like a String instead of a List?

Comment: No it doesn't work that way too.I tried removing throws Exception and passing few parameters it worked.But not sure why on removing  both it works

Answer (score 0):

We cannot use Number data type . We should use Long instead

Comment: This just doesn't relate to the question at all. Try being clearer in your questions and response for future inquiry.